# attach jQuery Resizable to 2 tables at once, so that the same column gets resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, javascript-framework, resizable

How can jQuery be applied in a particular instance, where two tables, 1 table being the header/column table and the other table containing the data. For example, if I were to resize a column in the header table, the column in the other table containing the data, would also be resized as well?

Can this be done or would it be considered "out of scope"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Table Scroll with Fixed Header</title>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
<tr>
  <td style="width: 150px">Column 1</td>
  <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div style="overflow: auto;height: 100px; width: 320px;">
  <table style="width: 300px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px">Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't full example, but I hope it will lead you to the solution.

You need to bind function to the *resize end* event ([jQuery API doc](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Resizable#event-resize)) and in the callback you can take the current item width and apply it to the other table column.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "resize", function(event, ui) {
   // TODO: you need to check index of the resized column and store it
   var width = $(ui).width();
   // TODO: find nth column from the other table and set it's width to be exactly same as
   // table 1
   $(".other-table-selector").width(width);
});
```